# Convert Mysql bool to python True/False

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
new_file.write(("""
    <cleared_for_hd_vod>%(enable_est_hd)s</cleared_for_hd_vod>
    <cleared_for_hd_sale>%(enable_vod_hd)s</cleared_for_hd_sale>"""
        % update_data).lower())
```

This gives me the following:

```
<cleared_for_hd_vod>1</cleared_for_hd_vod>
<cleared_for_hd_sale>0</cleared_for_hd_sale>
```

However, what I need is the following:

```
<cleared_for_hd_vod>true</cleared_for_hd_vod>
<cleared_for_hd_sale>false</cleared_for_hd_sale>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this by changing the string formatting I am currently using (at the top of this question) ?

Comment: would `bool(%(enable_est_hd)s)` not work?

Comment: How would that be written?

Comment: what's the python type of enable_vod_hd? what mysql connector are you using?

Comment: MySQLdb. It's a `TINYINT(1)`.

Comment: which template language are you using? you pasted half a statement, it's better if you paste all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#update_data={"enable_vod_hd": "1", "enable_est_hd": "1"}
newfile.write((
    """<cleared_for_hd_vod>%(enable_est_hd)s</cleared_for_hd_vod>
       <cleared_for_hd_sale>%(enable_vod_hd)s</cleared_for_hd_sale>
    """ %
    ({
      'enable_est_hd': bool(update_data["enable_est_hd"]),
      'enable_vod_hd': bool(update_data["enable_vod_hd"])
    })
).lower())
```